# How to make clap derive not convert underscores to hyphens in option names

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

With Clap's derive macro:

```rust
/// Simple program to greet a person
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Name of the person to greet
    #[arg(short, long)]
    full_name: String,
}
```

This will create a command line argument `--full-name`. Is there any way to make it use `--full_name` instead? Ideally with a global option rather than having to set it for each option individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either override arg name by providing `#[arg(long("custom_name")]`

```rust
/// Simple program to greet a person
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Name of the person to greet
    #[arg(short, long("full_name"))]
    full_name: String,
}
```

or if you want to use `snake_case` naming for all args you can change default renaming convention by setting `#[command(rename_all = "snake_case")]`

```rust
/// Simple program to greet a person
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None, rename_all = "snake_case")]
struct Args {
    /// Name of the person to greet
    #[arg(short, long)]
    full_name: String,
}
```

Comment: Refs: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#arg-attributes and 
https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#command-attributes